# French equivalents of "cost an arm and a leg"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Are there French equivalents to this phrase? I.e. a phrase which means something is very expensive. I've only found "coûter les yeux de la tête". Are there more?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd use:

> {informal}: coûter les yeux de la tête
>
> {informal}: coûter la peau des fesses
>
> {crude}: coûter la peau du cul
>
> {crude}: coûter la peau des couilles
>
> {informal}: coûter un bras
>
> {informal}: coûter un rein
>
> {informal}: coûter une blinde
>
> {informal}: coûter bonbon
>
> {informal}: coûter un prix fou
>
> {informal}: chiffrer [as in: ça va chiffrer]
>
> {slang}: douiller [as in: ça va douiller]

Comment: bravo. Il y a aussi "ça m'a coûté un saladier (de biftons)"

Comment: @user45784 jamais entendu celui-là. Original !

Comment: Never heard of the _saladier_-thing either. I like the order in which you've put the first four answers. They are the most common I think, and also in the right order for most informal to most crude. I would flag #2 as a bit less informal than #1, and #4 as much cruder than #3.

Comment: En verlan : "c'est super rech!".

Comment: @dda, it is, isn't it?! C'est savoyard, mon beau-frère dit tout le temps ça.

Comment: J'ajoute aussi "coûter un oeil", que je croyais avoir vu ici mais non..! Alors je ne sais pas si c'est quand ça coûte exactement moitié moins que les yeux de la tête mais bon, ça existe aussi ! :)

Comment: @EricDuminil C'est plus correct d'écrire "reuch", sinon ça induit en erreur pour la prononciation. L'orthographe est adaptée à la prononciation en verlan, pas besoin de coller à celle du mot original.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat: Je l'ai toujours entendu prononcé "rèche" ou "rêche".

Comment: @EricDuminil Ah bon ? Moi j'ai toujours entendu "reuch". Ça me paraît être la règle pour les mots qui finissent par une consonne ou consonne + "e" (cheum, chelou, keum, ...)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat: "Moche" ou "Louche" ne collent pas vraiment avec "cher". C'est vrai que "mec -> keum" semble impliquer "reuch" par contre.

Comment: il y a aussi "casquer" ("ça va casquer") https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/casquer

Answer (score 8):

Cinq autres expressions identifiées dans une monographie et en commentaire:

> Coûter un os, un pont. [Belgique]
>  Coûter le lard du chat, [un saladier](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28321/french-equivalents-of-cost-an-arm-and-a-leg#comment57436_28322).
>   [Suisse]
>  Coûter une beurrée. [Québec]
>
> [ [*Les expressions verbales figées de la francophonie: Belgique, France, Québec et Suisse*](https://books.google.com/books?id=i8H7u4KZAQQC&lpg=PA34&ots=G6V145yD_B&dq=%22co%C3%BBter%20une%20beurr%C3%A9e%22&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q=%22co%C3%BBter%20une%20beurr%C3%A9e%22&f=false), Béatrice Lamiroy, Jean-René Klein, *Editions OPHRYS*, 2010, p. 34 ]

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas "Le lard du chat" mais elle est vraiment bien car pas vraiment hyperbolique.

Answer (score 5):

Les meilleures réponses ont déjà été apportées, "ça coûte un bras" étant pour moi la plus utilisée de par chez nous (Sud-Est). Il me vient aussi "coûter un œil", que je croyais avoir vu plus haut et qui est aussi assez courant ici.

Maintenant, sur ces questions, je ne peux m'empêcher de sortir mon Duneton pour chercher et faire partager quelques perles de la langue française.

Nous avons donc, du milieu du XVIIème:

> Il en plumera la châtaigne (cela lui coûtera cher)
>   Le coût en fait perdre le goût ("la cherté de la chose en ôte la volonté" - Oudin)
>   Cela purge la bourse (attention au contexte...)
>   Il en a eu pour sa mine de fèves
>   Il me l'a bien salé (repris au XVIIIème avec "Saler une note")

On retrouve ensuite "Coûter les yeux de la tête" en 1867, "Coûter bonbon" au début du XXème (par plaisanterie sur "Coûter bon" du milieu XVIIème).

Mais bon, mieux vaut ne pas trop se disperser et rester dans les valeurs sûres de la réponse de Alone-zee pour se faire comprendre de nos jours !